# replace old values to new values in xml

Tags: c#, xml, string, architecture, replace

Hi I am trying to read xml string and trying to replace from old values to new values.. but dont now how to do this... because its read-only. NOTE: I DO NOT WANT TO USE STRING.REPLACE as this may be used in other ways like adding other elements.

```
string oldValue = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?><string>Hi This is old values</string>";

string newValue = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?><string>Hi I am the new values</string>";
```

Here is what Im trying to do :

```
     private string WriteXmlValue()
            {
                string currentXml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?><string>Hi This is old values</string>";

string newValue = "Hi I am the new values";
               string newXmlstring = string.empty;
                using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(currentXml)))
                {
                    while (xmlReader.Read())
                    {
                        switch (xmlReader.NodeType)
                        {
                            case XmlNodeType.Text:
                                //TODO Replace xmlReader.Value to newValue??
                                xmlReader.Value = newValue; //Erroring read only .. How do i modify value??
newXmlstring  = xmlReader.value;
                                break; 
                        }
                    }
                }
                return newXmlstring;
            }
```

I am then trying to return this new xmlstring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To play with the XML data if you are using .net version 3.5 its better to user [**LINQ to XML**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24376/LINQ-to-XML

**or**

[Manipulate XML data with XPath and XmlDocument (C#)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9494/Manipulate-XML-data-with-XPath-and-XmlDocument-C)